# Java: Anything similar to arrays as list for arrays?

Tags: java, arrays, list, collections

There is a way to get a `List` from `varargs` i.e. `Arrays.asList(o1, o2, o3 etc)`

Is there a similar way to get an `array`? E.g. something like `Arrays.asArray(o1, o2, o3 etc)`

**Update:**
`o1,o2,o3` is different types of objects

Comment: Arrays.asList(o1, o2, o3 etc).toArray()

Comment: Of course make sure you really *want* an object array for some (unfathomable) reason (http://stackoverflow.com/a/6105705/202214)

Answer (score 3):

You can use constructions as `String[] str = new String[] {"a", "b", "c"}`

Comment: `String[] str = {"a", "b", "c"};`

Answer (score 2):

varargs **are** array!

in `MyMethod(Param param, MyObject... args)` you can assign `MyObject[] array = args;`

Answer (score 1):

`List.toArray()` might be what you're looking for. Javadoc can be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray%28T%5b%5d%29).

Comment: I think he meant a method, that takes varags as a parameter, and allows to construct an array from them.

Answer (score 1):

Use something like this:

```
Element[] array = new Element[] { new Element(1),new Element(2),new Element(3) };
```

Or you could just create a list and convert it to an array. Here's an pretty good sample I got from java2s:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/** List to array */
public class ToArray {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    List list = new ArrayList();
    list.add("Blobbo");
    list.add("Cracked");
    list.add("Dumbo");
    // list.add(new Date()); // Don't mix and match!

    // Convert a collection to Object[], which can store objects
    // of any type.
    Object[] ol = list.toArray();
    System.out.println("Array of Object has length " + ol.length);

    // This would throw an ArrayStoreException if the line
    // "list.add(new Date())" above were uncommented.
    String[] sl = (String[]) list.toArray(new String[0]);
    System.out.println("Array of String has length " + sl.length);
  }
}
```

Comment: So it must be objects of same type in the list?What if I need objects of different types

Comment: @Jim well, you can post another question about that. :)

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean `varargs` to array? Just use it as an array, because it's already an array.

```
public void t(Object obj...) {
  Object obj0 = obj[0];
}
```

Or you said about array from static list? Then use construction of initialization like `Object objs = new Object[] {new Object, new Object, Object}`.

Also, from `List<T>` to array use method `List.toArray()`.

Or from `varargs` via `List` to array, just for fun:

```
public void t(Object obj...) {
 Object[] a = Arrays.asList(obj).toArray();
 // or
 Object[] b = Arrays.asList(new Object, new Object).toArray();
}
```

.

Answer (score 0):

See this example :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("a");
    list.add("b");
    list.add("c");
    list.add("d");
    list.add("e");
    list.add("f");
    String[] array = list.toArray(new String[0]); // Collection to array
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
        String contents = array[i];
        System.out.print(contents+"\t");
    }
    System.out.println();
    List<String> list2 = Arrays.asList(array); // Array back to Collection
    for (String s2 : list2) {
        String s3 = s2;
        System.out.print(s3+"\t");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either use ad-hoc array:

```
MyType[] arr = new MyType[]{new MyType(1), new MyType(2)...};
```

or create a little tricky method such as:

```
public static <T> T[] createArray(T... args) {
  return args;
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
MyType[] arr = createArray(new MyType(1), new MyType(2)...);
```

Comment: What is the ad hoc array in your first example.It doesn't compile for me

Comment: @Jim `MyType` here is just *any* type that you want to create an array from. And three dots, just before the closing curly brace, are there just to show, that you may add as many `MyType` instances as you want. Try this for example: `Object[] objArr = new Object[]{new Object(), new Object()};`

Answer (score 0):

You can assign the varargs to the same type array directly

```
static void intTest(int... v) {
  int[] arr = v;
}
static void objTest(Object... obj) {
    Object[] arr = obj;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
org.apache.commons.lang3.ArrayUtils
T ArrayUtils.toArray(T... t);
```

you welcome)

Comment: Please edit your answer and add some context by explaining how your answer solves the problem, instead of posting code-only answer. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/25052843)