# array index out of bound

Tags: java, arrays, string, indexoutofboundsexception

I want to create a combobox which takes names from database at runtime. So i created a empty string array but it throws an exception that arrayindexoutofbound. I think there's a mistake in initialization.....

```
            String s[]=new String[0];
            {
                 try
                {
                  Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
                  Connection con =DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:project","sa","123456");
                  Statement stmt= con.createStatement();
                  ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("SELECT Name FROM company");
                  i=0;
                  while(rs.next()) {        
                        s[i]=rs.getString(1);
                        i++;
                  }
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(f,ex);
                }
                cb=new JComboBox(s);
            }
```

Comment: Don't change the question while editing . Ask a new question.

Comment: JComboBox constructor only takes an array or Vector as input. You may convert you arraylist to array or use a vector instead.

Comment: Eg. `cb=new JComboBox(s.toArray())`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

An array is a container object that holds a fixed number of values of a single type. The length of an array is established when the array is created. After creation, its length is fixed. You are creating an array to hold 0 elements .

```
String s[]=new String[0]; //<< intialized with length 0
```

It will throw [`ArrayindexoutOfBoundsException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.html) when you try to access its 1st element `s[0]`.

> Thrown to indicate that an array has been accessed with an illegal index. **The index is either negative or greater than or equal to the size of the array.**

Size the size of your array is `0` , hence Exception is thrown while accessing index `0`.

Below a basic diagram of an array for understanding.

[image]

It is an array of length `10` , indexed from `0` to `9`.

Since you don't know the number of elements your data structure needs to store while declaring the array itself. It is better to use a dynamic [Collection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/index.html) in your case , probably any one of the implementation of [List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html) , like an [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html).

```
List<String> s = new ArrayList<String>();
while(rs.next())
{
   s.add(rs.getString("NAME")); // using column name instead of index "1" here
}
```

**Suggested Reading:**

1. [Oracle's tutorial on Java arrays](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html)
2. [Lists vs Arrays - when to use what](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12321242/lists-vs-arrays-when-to-use-what)

Answer (score 1):

You created  array with length 0. If u know how many members you need use array, if u dont know is better to use  ArrayList

Answer (score 1):

I am also working on a project getting data from database and adding it to a combobox, I prefer you to take it simple, there is no need to create an array, you just simply write:

```
 try
            {
              Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
              Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:project","sa","123456");
              Statement stmt= con.createStatement();
              ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("SELECT Name FROM company");
              cb=new JComboBox();
              while(rs.next()) {   
                    cb.addItem(rs.getString(1));
              }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(f,ex);
            }
```

Note: If you want to save data first and then add it to combobox, you should use Vector instead of array because it has limitation u will defined as told by

## The New Idiot

Answer (score 1):

You can also use Vector List:

```
 {

  Vector<String> namesList;

  try
        {
          Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
          Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:project","sa","123456");
          Statement stmt= con.createStatement();
          ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("SELECT Name FROM company");
          namesList = new Vector<>();

          while(rs.next()) {
                namesList.add(rs.getString(1));
          }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(f,ex);
        }
        cb=new JComboBox(namesList);
 }
```