# 3D Mapping Data Structure in Guava

Tags: java, data-structures, guava

I am implementing a genetic algorithm for constraint based university exam scheduling. For constraint checking to be efficient, I need data structures which contain most of the information before evaluation.

Right now I am using the `Table` structure from `Guava` as follows:

```
Table<Integer, Integer, ArrayList<Student>> clashesMatrix = HashBasedTable.create();
```

This means that I have students in common between exam i and exam j in a 2D matrix. However now I wish to take this a step further by having students in common between 3 exams i.e I need a sort of `3D matrix`. I need this because one of my constraints is to check for two or three consecutive exams in a row for students and it would be more efficient to have this kind of data before checking constraints.

Is there a particular data structure in `Guava` which could be used for this purpose? Or is there a way in which I can alter the Table above to cater for three exams perhaps?

I would appreciate your help since this is for my degree thesis! Thanks :)

Comment: Are you basically looking for an _easier_ structure to work with - that is essentially `Map<Integer, Map<Integer, Map<Integer, ArrayList<Student>>>>`?

Comment: yes @Scott I'm looking for something easier to work with. I found Table very easy to work with for 2D structure but when it comes to 3D I didn't find something similar yet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23181956/guava-table-vs-2d-array) already aimed at a similar direction. Now you need another dimension. And you added the (important!) information that the *keys* are always `Integer` values. As mentioned in my answer to your previous question, the autoboxing/autounboxing may have a performance impact here, but this should be noticable only for "large" data structures (deliberately not mentioning what exactly "large" means).

For a general, "N-dimensional" indexing, you might consider an own key type. Particularly, something like an `IntTuple`. (In fact, you could use a `List<Integer>` as the key type, but this may have some drawbacks). With such an `IntTuple` class, with proper implementations of `hashCode` and `equals`, you can easily define an arbitrary, N-dimensional data structure, that may be used in a form that is convenient and efficient:

```
Map<IntTuple, List<Student>> map = new HashMap<IntTuple, List<Student>>();

List<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>();

map.put(IntTuple.of(1,2,3), students);

List<Student> s = map.get(IntTuple.of(1,2,3));
```

However, **note** that depending on the exact queries that you want to make, a different structure may be more appropriate. For example, this structure does **not** allow queries like

> "Give me all students where the second element of the 'key tuple' has the value 'x'"

If you need this kind of query, then a different data structure may be more appropriate.

---

(I had such an `IntTuple` class in my "snippets directory", I'll insert it here for convenience...)

```
import java.util.Arrays;

class IntTuple 
{
    static IntTuple of(int ... values)
    {
        return new IntTuple(values);
    }

    private final int data[];
    private IntTuple(int ... data)
    {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public int getDimensions()
    {
        return data.length;
    }

    public int get(int index)
    {
        return data[index];
    }
    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return Arrays.toString(data);
    }
    @Override
    public int hashCode()
    {
        return Arrays.hashCode(data);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object)
    {
        if (this == object)
        {
            return true;
        }
        if (object == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        if (!(object instanceof IntTuple))
        {
            return false;
        }
        IntTuple other = (IntTuple)object;
        return Arrays.equals(data, other.data);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed answer :) I have to look into what exact queries I need from my data structure first as you pointed out, but this was very interesting and if I don't have any specific queries, I will go for it. Do you have any suggestions regarding other similar data structures that you know of?

Comment: @Bernice None in particular. I already pointed out in my answer to the other question that the possibility to obtain *either* rows *or* columns from a Guava Table can be a neat feature, but particulularly for higher dimensions, things may become tricky: The queries may then refer to "slices" (or "subspaces") with arbitrary dimensions. E.g. 1D: "Give me all elements with coordinates (3,4,x) for arbitrary x", or 2D: "Give me all elements with coordinates (3,y,x) for arbitrary x and y" and so on. It really depends on what you want to **do** with this data structure.