# Why do we need to convert array into a list before storing it in a HashSet?

Tags: arrays, list, hashset

I have a program that looks like the following attached image, and I'm wondering why the initial array "words" needs to be converted into a list before it can be stored in a HashSet. Can I store it directly in a HashSet? Thank you in advance!

public class Starter {

```
public int begins(String[] words, String first) {

    HashSet<String> hset = new HashSet(Arrays.asList(words));

    char firstChar = first.charAt(0);

    int total = 0;
    for (String i : hset) {
        if (firstChar == (i.charAt(0))) {
            total += 1;
        }
    }
    return total;
}
```

}

Comment: The obvious answer is that there's no HashSet constructor which accepts arrays. That may be because collections are generally preferred. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6100148/collection-interface-vs-arrays

Answer (score 0):

1. The reason for converting the array into ArrayList is -> `HashSet` doesn't take an array as a direct argument.
2. The reason for using `HashSet` is as it implements `Set` interface it remove all the duplicate entries and keeps distinct values. For the same reason, you could not check the first letter of a word which occurs multiple times.

So therefore below codes give you output as: `2`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(new Solution().begins(new String[] {"hell", "hell", "hock", "tese"}, "h"));
    }
    
    public int begins(String[] words, String first) {

        HashSet<String> hset = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(words));

        System.out.println(hset);
        char firstChar = first.charAt(0);

        int total = 0;
        for (String i : hset) {
            if (firstChar == (i.charAt(0))) {
                total += 1;
            }
        }
        return total;
    }
```